# how to prove $[D_{\beta}, D_{\alpha}]AB=([D_{\beta}, D_{\alpha}]A)B+([D_{\beta}, D_{\alpha}]B)A$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity, index-notation

Where $A$, $B$ are arbitrary scalars, four-vectors,  or tensors

we have this property:
$$
[D_a, D_b]V^c=R^c_{eba}V^e
$$
with $R^c _{eba}$  is the Riemann tensor

Comment: Welcome. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've edited it, please double-check if correct.

Comment: that's very good! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straighforward calculation gives
$$
(D_\beta D_\alpha) (A B) = D_\beta ((D_\alpha A) B + A (D_\alpha B)) \\
= (D_\beta D_\alpha A) B + (D_\alpha A) (D_\beta B) + (D_\beta A) (D_\alpha B) + A (D_\beta D_\alpha B)
$$

By just swapping $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have
$$
(D_\alpha D_\beta) (A B)
= (D_\alpha D_\beta A) B + (D_\beta A) (D_\alpha B) + (D_\alpha A) (D_\beta B) + A (D_\alpha D_\beta B)
$$

Subtracting the second one from the former gives
$$[D_\beta, D_\alpha](AB) = ([D_\beta, D_\alpha]A) B + A ([D_\beta, D_\alpha] B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're given that $D_\alpha$ and $D_\beta$ are derivations and that $[D_\beta,D_\alpha]$ means their commutator $D_\beta D_\alpha-D_\alpha D_\beta$. With all that, just write out both sides of your desired equation, apply the hypotheses that $D_\alpha$and $D_\beta$ are derivations, cancel some terms, and observe that the two sides are the same.